# Powershell - Trim word document

Tags: powershell, powershell-3.0

I have a word document, that I read with the following code:

```
$objWord = New-Object -Com Word.Application
$objWord.Visible = $false
$objDocument = $objWord.Documents.Open($Formularpath, $false, $true)
$documenttext = $objDocument.wordopenxml
```

Now I have my document, but there is alot of text I don't need. How can I cut the text, e.g. until 1 specific word? I know split(';') but I will need a whole word...

Comment: wordopenxml returns xml so you probably want to select a specifiy node?

Comment: What do you intend to do with the text? Save it back to the original document?

Comment: I need some values from the text, e.g. Name and want to generate AD users. I need many values from the document (about 20)